# Hive table not retrieving rows from external file

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a text file called as sample.txt. The file looks like:

`abc,23,M
def,25,F
efg,25,F`

I am trying to create a table in hive using:

`CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE ppldb(name string, age int,gender string) 
ROW FORMAT
DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/path/to/sample.txt';`

But the data isn't getting into the table. When I run the query:

`select count(*) from ppldb`

I get 0 in output.

What could be the reason for data not getting loaded into the table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The location in a **external** table in Hive should be an **HDFS directory** and not the full path of the file.
If that directory does not exists then the location we give will be created automatically. In your case **/path/to/sample.txt** is being treated as a **directory**.

So just give the **/path/to/** in the **LOCATION** and keep the sample.txt file inside the directory. It will work.

Hope it helps...!!!

Answer (score 2):

the `LOCATION` clause indicates where the table will be stored, not where to retrieve data from. After moving the samples.txt file into hdfs with something like

```
hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal ~/samples.txt /user/tables/
```

you could load the data into a table in hive with

```
create table temp(name string, age int, gender string)
row format delimited fields terminated by ','
stored as textfile;

load data inpath '/user/tables/samples.txt' into table temp;
```

That should work